# Alert is not working in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Non of the following are not working in ASP.Net

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Record inserted')</script>");
```

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Record Inserted Successfully')", true);
```

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Insert is successful')", true);
```

I want to alert when data inserted. I use all above but not works.

Comment: Response.Write("<script>alert('Record inserted')</<script>>")

Comment: use this also....

Comment: At which event do you call it? At Page_Load ? Did you set a breakpoint to see if the command is executed ?

Comment: if command executed

Comment: I used ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock, first command in Page_Load and it worked for me. The script was also visible when I inspected the HTML rendered afterwards. Can you post the full code of your event ?

Comment: please follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176493/how-to-fire-js-from-code-behind-of-a-usercontrol-by-an-event/25176553#25176553