# Alert script goes wrong

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, alert

I am using below alert script in VB.net

```
Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('please select the data first!');</script>")
```

But after executing the code my menu table enhanced like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIvUv.png) Menu before executing the code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Mubj.png)
something wrong with the code that causes such abnormal change.

The menu asp.net code is as below:

```
<table align ="right"  width="400" border="1" class="table" style="border: thin outset #000000; background-image: url('Images/Red.png'); color: #FFFFFF;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnConvert" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text="Convert to Pipeline" ValidationGroup="ChangeStatus"  />
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style8">
            <a href="CreateRecords.aspx" style="color: #FFFFFF">||Home</a>
            <div class="item-container">
            </div>
        </td>  
        <td class="auto-style8">
            <a href="Reports.aspx" style="color: #FFFFFF">||Reports</a>
            <div class="item-container">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: please follow the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176493/how-to-fire-js-from-code-behind-of-a-usercontrol-by-an-event/25176553#25176553

Comment: the second one worked for me. thank you.

Comment: you welcome @iram

Comment: is there any one liner script for confirmation Alert on the button event (yes, No)

Comment: iram, try with "confirm" instead of "alert"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(Page), "somekey", "alert('please select the data first!');", True)
```